# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I'm having no luck upgrading my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. At every attempt, the upgrade process is interrupted with this message:

[image]

What do I do?

*

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for jakub: 
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnumdk/lollypop/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease [5 931 B] 
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:8 ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:10 ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/linux/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:11 ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/linux/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease           
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/linux/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Fetched 5 931 B in 2s (3 342 B/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
jakub@Sulaco:~$*
```

Thanks!

Comment: @user535733 done

Comment: You can download the iso of Ubuntu 22.04, and flash it to a USB drive, and install it.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached end of standard support in May 2023. This means it can't be upgraded to 20.04 in the normal way. See the link below for how to upgrade from an obsolete version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Does 18.04 qualify as a 'very old Ubuntu', really? The topic you've linked seems to mostly refer to actually ancient versions, like 9.04.

Comment: @kubakonrad the same applies to any out-of-support versions. 18.04 is older now than 9.04 was when the question was written.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have any `bionic-updates` sources, nor any `bionic-security` sources. Those are required for a properly-functioning Ubuntu system.

That is the most likely cause of your current problem. Turn those back on, install the mountain of updates thence, and then try your release-upgrade again.

Those sources don't get turned off automatically. A human did that.

The lack of security updates may be a serious problem: Were you on my network, you would be required to do a full wipe-and-reinstall. If you don't recall how or why those sources were disabled, then a reinstall might be a very good idea.

Comment: It doesn't matter because the OP is trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 from it.

Comment: @user535733 I did not turn off anything:

https://ibb.co/Q9RJqg6